# Using a Convection oven. Do I use the same temperature as a Fan oven?

Tags: oven

I am using a Convection oven. Do I set the temperature the same as a fan oven?
(Eg instructions only mention 190c Fan or 200c Electric for 25-30minutes)
Unable to find a basic temperature conversion chart. Just Electric/Fan!

Comment: In my experience the manual that came with the oven usually has information on this type of thing.

Comment: Yes I’d say this would be very oven specific.  A further factor is inaccuracy of many oven thermostats.  I would say it also depends on what you are doing.  Baking is typically more sensitive than a stew say.  For roasts use a probe !!,  Document your results and learn your oven.

Answer (score -1):

The temperature of the food raises faster in case of the oven with a fan, so you have to set a higher temperature in a conventional oven than a fan (Convection) oven. 
It is not possible to have any conversion chart as between them, because how fast the temperature of food raises depends on the food itself. So, some experienced has to be gained while using conventional(without fan) oven keeping in mind the first point I mentioned- "In most of the cases, temperature you have to set this time will be higher than an oven with a fan".

Comment: I am sorry to downvote, and especially hate doing it with a new user's first answer, but it is simply incorrect to say that you have to set a higher temperature in a convection oven than in a fan oven, because the two are the same kind of oven. So you always use the same temperature. And even if you misunderstood the terms and thought that the convection oven is without a fan, there are conversion charts which work very well in practice.

Comment: Maybe a confusion of convection with conventional?

Comment: Ya, sorry... it is 'conventional' not 'convection'!